# How to built and print a scannable Pass for Passbook in iOS7

Tags: ios7, qr-code, passbook

i can't figure out how to build a OR Code for a Pass that is scannable with the new QR code scanner in iOS7' Passbook App.

When I try to scan a QR Code with a link to a working Pass, the App says it is 'No Pass available for this Card'. Card, hum?!

Any ideas?

Comment: Scanning is fninally working. Had to put the .pkpass on a https server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a pass to install, the following criteria have to be met:

- The link must be https
- The URL must return a valid `.pkpass` bundle
- The `Content-Type` header must be `application/vnd.apple.pkpass`

Unfortunately, these requirements are not yet documented, but they are mentioned in the WWDC session [What's new in Passbook](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/?id=302)

Comment: I confirm, https and mime-type required! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The URL contained in the QR code must return a valid PKPASS file and have the correct MIME type in the HTTP response.

Does that help?

Comment: i think, i am missing https here. MIME/type and .pkpass are correct.

Comment: Yes, I believe that's also a requirement.

Comment: Hi @poolsideDev, have you solved with https? thank you everyone

Comment: @MaRco85 Yes, as far i can remember to content-type wasnt set correctly. See PassKits answer